# couchDB RHEL4 Install Error

Tags: installation, couchdb, redhat

I'm currently trying to install couchDB on a Red Hat 4 machine

> Linux version 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b18n3.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Dec 6 19:48:22 GMT 2011

following the instructions on the Apache Wiki: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_RHEL4. The install runs fine right up until the line

> make && sudo make install

when i get the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/erlc   couch_key_tree.erl;
./couch_key_tree.erl:78: type boolean() undefined
./couch_key_tree.erl:79: type boolean() undefined
./couch_key_tree.erl:93: type boolean() undefined
./couch_key_tree.erl:136: type boolean() undefined
make[4]: *** [couch_key_tree.beam] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/acarter/couchdb/src/couchdb'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/acarter/couchdb/src/couchdb'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/acarter/couchdb/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/acarter/couchdb'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've looked around online and seen the problem mentioned once or twice but never a solution. Does anyone know a solution or a good place to start looking?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this same issue.  The problem is that the version of Erlang is outdated(12B in my case).  The solution was to upgrade to a newer version.

Source:
https://github.com/cloudant/bigcouch/issues/13